# A CSS Site displays correctly in both FireFox and Chrome, but the border radius with IE11 does not display correctly

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

A CSS Site displays correctly in both FireFox and Chrome, but the border radius with IE11 does not display correctly.

Link: http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx

Comment: @ hashim Where do you want the border-radius? all `input` elements or just `type=text`, `div`.....?

Comment: Without an actual explanation, the only conjecture I can make is that you didn't apply the css property `border-radius` and are relying on the user-agent stylesheets of **firefox** and **chrome**. `border-radius` works in **ie11** - [browser support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

Comment: border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;    these two property i write it but not working with ie11

Comment: I don't see the `border-radius` style applied to the `.breadcrumb` class

Comment: .breadcrumb a:after   .breadcrumb a:before   check these u will find border-radius

Comment: Let me take a look in browser shots...I have a mac

Comment: Check the doctype. Try `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Fixed some grammar and the link as well

Comment: @hashim Change the doctype. Try `<!DOCTYPE html>` and let me know if that fixes the issue with the psuedo-elements styling

Comment: okay i Try <!DOCTYPE html> but still

Comment: @hashim Check my answer. Remove the `content="IE=EmulateIE8"`. If that doesn't work, post your code so I can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the doctype. Add the The `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration before the html.

**Remove**  `content="IE=EmulateIE8"` from `<meta>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

- You are emulating IE8. `border-radius` is only compatible with IE9+.
- Replace with `content="IE=edge"` to tell Internet Explorer to use the latest engine to render the page.
- If you need to target IE8 in the page, better are [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

  ```
  <!--[if IE 8]>
      <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.</p>
  <![endif]-->
  ```

Comment: Where you place the doctype is not based on preference. It's the very first thing on the very first line at all times.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the edit. My mistake. I meant to say that the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype as opposed to the one for XHTML Traditional is *my preference* and that the latter portion of the answer is the actual solution.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> this one i used it

Comment: @hashim - The culprit is the `meta` tag emulating IE8. Did you remove that?

Comment: @hashim No one should be using the transitional doctype since 1999 for new web pages. That was only used to help developers transition web sites from older versions of HTML to newer ones. Never use transitional for new web sites, and don't use the XHTML one if you aren't serving your pages as application/xhtml+xml. Otherwise you're only serving up 'tag soup'.